# How to verify whether a connection pool has beem set up in spring MVC web app?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

In one of my question asked earlier I got to know that `DriverManagerDataSource` is **NOT** intended for production use. So I changed my configuration. I know I am using DBCP which is also outdated and a lot of other connection pools are available like HIkariCP and BOneCP but

> I wish to understand the way how to verify that a pool has been setup
>   or not?

On searching a lot I got some answer at the following link 
[How would you test a Connection Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134515/how-would-you-test-a-connection-pool)

but I didn't get a way to verify programmatically. Also I cannot debug my jar files used for connection pooling because no source code is available. I dont know why but I can't change my jars for offical reasons.

The following are my configuration (OLD and NEW)

**OLD**

```
<bean id="webLogicXADataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="#[csa.db.driver]" />
        <property name="url" value="#[csa.db.url]" />
        <property name="username" value="#[csa.db.username]" />
        <property name="password" value="#[csa.db.password]" />     
    </bean>
```

**NEW**
Using DBCP connection pool

```
<bean id="webLogicXADataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="#[csa.db.driver]" />
        <property name="url" value="#[csa.db.url]" />
        <property name="username" value="#[csa.db.username]" />
        <property name="password" value="#[csa.db.password]" />     
    </bean>
```

**OTHER ELEMENTS:**(Thus far I have kept them same like they were earlier)

> Place holder

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>              
                <value>file:${DB_PROPERTIES}</value>                
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="#[" />
        <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]" />
    </bean>
```

> Transaction Manager

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="webLogicXADataSource" />
        <qualifier value="inventoryTxManager"/>
    </bean>
```

> DAOIMPL SAMPLE BEAN

```
<bean id="inventoryDao"
        class="com.lxnx.fab.ce.icce.inventoryRoutingInvoice.dao.InventoryDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="webLogicXADataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
```

Right now all the DAO classes in my project are singleton(no prototype property set for any of the beans)

The following is the sample java code of the DAOImpl.java class where I need to do all the transactions:

**DAOImpl.java**

```
public class InventoryDaoImpl implements InventoryDao {
    private final static ISmLog iSmLog = Instrumentation
            .getSmLog(LNConstants.SYSTEM_LOG_NAME); 

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }   

    public void setTransactionManager(
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

@Transactional private void insertRelatedInfoData(
        InventoryModel inventoryModel) {
            final List<String> relatedLniList = inventoryModel.getArrRelatedLni();                  
            final String documentLni  = inventoryModel.getDocumentLNI();        
            String sql = "INSERT INTO SCSMD_REPO.INV_RELATED_INFO(LNI, RELATED_LNI) VALUES(?,?)";
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    String relatedLni = relatedLniList.get(i);
                    ps.setString(1, documentLni);
                    ps.setString(2, relatedLni);            
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return relatedLniList.size();
                }
              });   
    }

}
```

I am not getting any errors. Just wanted to verify If a pool has been setup U wish to verify the same

Are all configurations fine or did I miss something?? Please help me out with you valuable answers. thanks

Comment: The datasource you are using is a connection pool so it is setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hey . Can you please tell me how can I verify the same in real time?

Comment: Please check the logs for you application. The connection pool will be loaded on when the Database manager is loaded.

Comment: You cannot... As it is a `Datasource` it can or cannot be a pool. There is no unified way of checking that. But the fact that you configured it should be enough, why on earth would you want to introduce the complexity of trying to check it?!

Comment: If you don't have logs enable then you can't verify it. however there is one more donkey logic

Comment: @M.Deinum , Karan Verma , Tipu

Now ,I just wanted to confirm whether the connection would be returned automatically to the pool in this scenario ? Since I am not doing anything for the same?

Comment: Because you don't need to do anything. As mentioned it is a `DataSource` and that should/is transparantly  handled for you by the implementation.

Comment: Oh great thanks..! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have logs enable then you can't verify it. however there is one more donkey logic.

every database server will have timeout functionality. if db not hit by application after some time connection will break. for example mysql server will break it's connection from application after `8 hour` (if there is no hit from application). you check modify timeout to minimum time (say 30 min)in mysql config file and check after `30 minute`s you get connection close exception in you appication, when you hit db

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, as explained, would be to examine the logs. It's quite likely that a connection pool will log something, at least if your logging level is low enough.

Another way would be to examine the class of the `Connection` that the datasource returns. If you're dealing with a connection pool, the class will be a wrapper or a proxy class for that pool. The wrapper/proxy class makes sure that when you call `close()` the connection isn't really closed, it's just returned to the pool for further use. For example if you were to use `HikariCP` as your pool, you could check `if(connection instanceof IHikariConnectionProxy)` to see if the pool is being used.

Adding that kind of code in your software would be a bad idea in practically all cases. If you don't know whether a connection pool is being used or not, it's not something you solve with code. It's something you solve by reading and studying more.

You've also named your bean `webLogicXADataSource` even though nothing seems to support it being an XA datasource. Are you perhaps working on things a bit too advanced for you?

Comment: Exactly , Things are quite advanced for me I have never worked before on XA datasources

The only log message I get is 
`06:26:53.668(03/21) INFO  APP : Setting the datasource`

Is that fine a pool has been set up ?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't trust that. It might also indicate that your logging isn't properly set up.

Comment: I am using a logging api which is kind of wrapper for the log4j and 
Now ,I just wanted to confirm whether the connection would be returned automatically to the pool in this scenario or not ? Since I am not doing anything for the same?