# How get connection pool from jdbcTemaplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Ok I have ingested `jdbcTemplate` into some class:

```
@Service
public MyService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
   
}
```

But how to get connection pool implementation from it? I see `getDataSource()` method but `DataSource` does not have something about conenction pool :(

Comment: I think this might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913123/how-to-verify-whether-a-connection-pool-has-beem-set-up-in-spring-mvc-web-app

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have this dependency in your dependency manager

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The implementation for the `DataSource` interface is going to be `HikariDataSource` and this is the instance Spring is going to use for construction of `JdbcTemplate`.

Now when you call `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()` in your code `HikariDataSource` gets you a connection from the pool.

If you are interested in code:

```
   @Override
   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
   {
      if (isClosed()) {
         throw new SQLException("HikariDataSource " + this + " has been closed.");
      }

      if (fastPathPool != null) {
         return fastPathPool.getConnection();
      }

      // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java
      HikariPool result = pool;
      if (result == null) {
         synchronized (this) {
            result = pool;
            if (result == null) {
               validate();
               LOGGER.info("{} - Starting...", getPoolName());
               try {
                  pool = result = new HikariPool(this);
                  this.seal();
               }
               catch (PoolInitializationException pie) {
                  if (pie.getCause() instanceof SQLException) {
                     throw (SQLException) pie.getCause();
                  }
                  else {
                     throw pie;
                  }
               }
               LOGGER.info("{} - Start completed.", getPoolName());
            }
         }
      }

      return result.getConnection();
    }
```