# How can I check out whether c3p0's Connection Pooling work in my project?

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

everyone!

I’m trying for the first time in my life to use a pool of connections. I want to apply it to my project on Java + Tomcat + maven + Spring MVC + Spring Security + Hibernate. As a library with the implementation of a connections pooling, I decided to use c3p0 library.

I added the dependencies for c3p0 to pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-rest-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>FirstRestProject</name>
    <description>CRUD methods testing in the REST API app</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <springframework.version>5.1.7.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jackson.library>2.9.8</jackson.library>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate-c3p0 Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson API for JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Embedded Apache Tomcat required for testing war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I added c3p0’s connection pooling settings to file db.properties:

```
# MySQL properties
mysql.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/service
mysql.user=root
mysql.password=****

# Hibernate properties
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

#C3P0 properties
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=1
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=2
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=3000
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
```

I think this is enough to c3p0’s connection pool work. But I do not know whether it works or not.
When I run my application (in IDE), I see that there are  minPoolSize->1 and maxPoolSize->2 in the server logs. But how I can test it in practice? If I used JDBC requests, I would try to create multiple Connections. But I work with ORM, in other words with sessions. How to do it there? I tried the following: I sent 3 GET requests from 3 different browsers (they execute access to the database), but despite the fact that maxPoolSize=2, all 3 ones were executed successfully.

The code of my DAO class:

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.model.User;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.criteria.*;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Integer save(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public User get(Integer id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User get(String username) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User u where u.username = :login");
        query.setParameter("login", username);
        return (User) query.getResultList().get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Integer id, User user2) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user1 = session.byId(User.class).load(id);
        user1.setUsername(user2.getUsername());
        user1.setPassword(user2.getPassword());
        user1.setId_role(user2.getId_role());
        user1.setName(user2.getName());
        user1.setSurname(user2.getSurname());
        user1.setEmail(user2.getEmail());
        user1.setBirth(user2.getBirth());
        session.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user = session.byId(User.class).load(id);
        session.delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.select(root);
        Query<User> query = session.createQuery(cq);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

The code of my Hibernate configuration class:

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.*;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import static org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.*;

import java.util.Properties;

/*
Hibernate configuration class
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.example.dao"),  @ComponentScan("com.example.service")})
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        // Setting JDBC properties
        props.put(DRIVER, env.getProperty("mysql.driver"));
        props.put(URL, env.getProperty("mysql.url"));
        props.put(USER, env.getProperty("mysql.user"));
        props.put(PASS, env.getProperty("mysql.password"));

        // Setting Hibernate properties
        props.put(SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        props.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        // Setting C3P0 properties
        props.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size"));
        props.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size"));
        props.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment"));
        props.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout"));
        props.put(C3P0_IDLE_TEST_PERIOD, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"));
        props.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"));

        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.model");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Does connection pooling work in my case? How I can check it out? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any answers or links.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134515/how-would-you-test-a-connection-pool

Comment: @user7294900 Thank you for an interesting link. I've acquainted with issue it refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `show processlist` to check the active connections and their various properties at any one time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Really, I use MySQL :) And when I change my minPoolSize, the number of connections is appropriately changed too (I see it via your query). When the server is not starting, my MySQL shows me 3 connections by default. When I set min-max pool size to 2-3, I have 3+2 connections. When 3-5, I have 3+3 connections. And so on I have the number of connections equals to 3 + minPoolSize. But when I set 1-2 I get 3+2 connections for some reason. The 1-1 setting give me 3+1 connection. There is an interesting thing :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161663/2834978) for another method to indirectly check pool connections.